# Getting error in linkedin OAuth integration, Despite passing correct information as per linked in guide

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

We are working on LinkedIn API integration in our application. In that we are getting error in Step 2 ( below )

We are following below link, And doing same but still facing issue
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Please guide as we have been trying it since last week on same issue

**Step 1**

```
**Request from Browser**
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1239%2FSocial%2FLinkedIn_Callback&state=a10b20c30

**Response**
http://localhost:1239/Social/LinkedIn_Callback?code=AQQ1HqrimUyzhJ621l9v63yKgwRdOie_G4_r-BjAW8hpW8mUjd67Q04OOTkCyUOGFGdJNdehIcr-2H08ktsSQhiAeyiKC3rG2D6_QlNgHbJnla7fuME&state=a10b20c30
```

**Step 2**

**Request**

```
POST /uas/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Host: www.linkedin.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1239%2FSocial%2FLinkedIn_Callback&client_id={ actual client_Id }&client_secret={ actual client_secret }&code=AQQ1HqrimUyzhJ621l9v63yKgwRdOie_G4_r-BjAW8hpW8mUjd67Q04OOTkCyUOGFGdJNdehIcr-2H08ktsSQhiAeyiKC3rG2D6_QlNgHbJnla7fuME
```

**Response**

> {    "error_description": "missing required parameters, includes an
>   invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to
>   retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match
>   authorization code or authorization code expired",
>       "error": "invalid_request" }

I have tried this many times but same response i am getting.
I have checked Api Id, Secret Id, Call Back URL at Linked In Developer Settings and all is ok what we are passing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Authorization tokens have a very short time-to-live.  Ensure that you are making the token request call in step two immediately afterwards, so that the authorization token hasn't expired by the time you are trying to use it.

If you try and do this process manually, it's easy to take too long copying and pasting things from browser windows to obtain a token.

If you're doing it from within code, ensure that you the server you're running from is able to successfully communicate with the LinkedIn API server and isn't getting tripped up on an SSL certificate trust issue or something like that that's causing the calls to take longer than expected.